# Stack Exchange Fellowship and Grant Program: Looking for reviewers to assess thesis proposals

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange will be introducing a Fellowship Program awarding grants for original and independent research projects. Undergraduate Honors Theses, Independent Study Projects, Masters Theses, and Dissertations are eligible projects.

Prospective fellows will be asked to demonstrate a commitment to the discipline, approval or guidance of faculty adviser, two page proposal of the project and abstract.

Before officially introducing the Fellowship Program and calling for applications, we need experienced community members to volunteer to review applicants' two page proposals and abstracts.

Stack Exchange Fellows will be in the following subjects:

- Philosophy
- Statistics
- Linguistics
- Physics
- English

Interested in being a reviewer? Contact Seth Rogers (seth at stackexchange dot com). Reviewers are honored as Committee Members and receive a small gift as our way of saying thank you.

Comment: The program has been officially announced! Check out [this post](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/266/introducing-the-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program) for the application, reviewer sheet, and more info. And please spread the word to potential applicants!

Answer (score 2):

Am I correct in assuming that reviewers would not be eligible to apply for Fellowships?

Comment: Presuming reviewers fit the qualifications to apply for the fellowship (which will be forthcoming) then they can apply. We will direct their applications to another panel member to ensure objectivity.

Comment: Cool.  In that case, count me in.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be honored to help! What should I do next?

Comment: Hi Jaime - sorry it took us so long to get back to you about this! I'm going to send you an email with more information.